# Is transaction (multi, exec) supported in spring data redis in a cluster mode?

Tags: transactions, redis, cluster-computing, jedis, spring-data-redis

I had implemented (and tested) transaction operation in redis using multi and exec functionality in a single REDIS instance successfully. However, the same code running in a cluster setup erroring out with the following exception message. I am using spring-data-redis-1.8.1.RELEASE and jedis-2.9.0.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: MUTLI is currently not supported in cluster mode.
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisClusterConnection.multi(JedisClusterConnection.java:2457)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultStringRedisConnection.multi(DefaultStringRedisConnection.java:608)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate$21.doInRedis(RedisTemplate.java:871)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:207)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:169)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.multi(RedisTemplate.java:868)
    at com.glu.centech.chat.RedisClusterTest$1.execute(RedisClusterTest.java:58)
    at com.glu.centech.chat.RedisClusterTest$1.execute(RedisClusterTest.java:1)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:229)
    at com.glu.centech.chat.RedisClusterTest.main(RedisClusterTest.java:55)
```

Is transaction (multi, exec) currently supported in spring data redis in a cluster mode? If so, what am I missing? If not, is there any workaround or when it'll be supported?

Answer (score 0):

There's no transaction support for Redis Cluster with Spring Data Redis and you should not expect it to be implemented. See [Is there any Redis client (Java prefered) which supports transactions on Redis cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42088324/is-there-any-redis-client-java-prefered-which-supports-transactions-on-redis-c/42091605#42091605) for further reference.